# How to bind TextBox to a nullable property only if a CheckBox is checked

Tags: c#, winforms, data-binding, nullable

I need to bind `TextBox.Text` to a property if the `CheckBox` next to it is checked. Otherwise the value of property should be null.

[image: TextBox binding to nullable]

Let's say DTO Class is like:

```
public class DataForInputDTO 
{
    public double? Power {get; set;}
    public double? Speed {get; set;} 
    // Other Properties
}
```

Now, when user unchecks the *Speed* `CheckBox` the `TextBox` next to it gets disabled (This is OK) but I also need the property *Speed* to get null instead of *60*.
Is there any way to do this without manually changing the binding at `CheckBox.CheckedChaneg`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set via the property to which the Speed CheckBox is bound to. For example, if the IsChecked Property of Speed checkbox is bound to a property called IsSpeedChecked, you could do the following.

```
    private double _powerValue = 0;

    public double? Power { get; set; } = 0;

    public bool IsPowerEnabled
    {
        get => _isPowerEnabled;
        set
        {
            _isPowerEnabled = value;
            if (!value)
            {
                _powerValue = Power.Value;
                Power = null;
            }
            else
            {
                Power = _powerValue;
            }
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(Power));
            NotifyOfPropertyChange(nameof(IsPowerEnabled));
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Its a good idea to make it null, but does this change Speed back to 60 when the checkbox is checked again?

Comment: @roozbehS in that scenario, you might have to keep a backup of value in a variable. I have updated the answer with sample